# Which iCloud account does iBooks use to sync?

Tags: icloud, books, macos

Does the new iBooks app for OS X Mavericks sync notes, bookmarks, read position, etc. using one's iCloud account, or one's iTunes Store account?

In other words, if two people use separate Apple IDs for their iCloud accounts, but use the same Apple ID for the iTunes Store to share purchases, will their read positions and notes remain distinct or conflict with each other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **iBooks app on iOS as well as OS X Mavericks uses the account you use to sign into the iBooks Store for syncing** bookmarks, notes, collections, highlights and purchased books. So if you share an Apple ID/iTunes Store Account for purchases from the iBooks Store, then the sync will affect all the users who share the account.

The **iBooks sync is not based on one's individual iCloud account,** which is used for iMessage, FaceTime, Mail, Calendar, etc.

See [iBooks: How to sync iBooks between devices](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT5826) for more information.

Comment: That's what I expected, and it sucks. Thanks for the confirmation.

Answer (score 1):

The iTunes Store account's Apple ID (not the iCloud account). And so, yes, the reading locations will be synced unless you disable that option.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to use both. From what I can tell, the iCloud account syncs your bookmarks etc., while the "collections" are stored in your store account. My wife and I use the same store account but have different iCloud accounts. While we have our own highlights and bookmarks, our collections lists are the same.

Answer (score 0):

I have a different Apple ID for iCloud and the iTunes Store. When I tried to download from the iBooks Store using macOS El Capitan iBooks it would only accept my iCloud ID -- though if I'd purchases anything from iBooks that would have been through my iTunes Store ID. (I don't purchase from iBook Store because of problems like this).

I Francisco is correct about the sync, but there is something odd about purchase sync.